# Creating and running WPF window in another thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, console

So I am working on a console project which should display a WPF window at some point where I can see the visual representation of my graph while it continues running through the algorithm.

I've come so far that I can create a Window and open it in another thread, but as soon as I call `Dispatcher.Run()` the Console gets blocked. My approach so far:

*Step 1*: Creating a thread which creates the `Application` and an `SynchronizationContext` for itself once run

*Step 2*: Calling the application's method (it's an inherited custom class which provides these methods) to create a window using a transportation class, using the sync-context of the thread. **Expectation**: It should create an instance of a Window owned by the separate UI thread.

*Step 3*: Calling the `ShowWindow()` method on the application using the sync-context of the thread, which shows the Window (does work) and then runs the Dispatcher. Because it's dispatched using the sync-context of the thread, it shouldn't lock the Console thread. *It does, though*.

*Step 4*: Using the Window's dispatcher to call the update methods for the graph.

Well, in my thoughts this should perfectly well work, but somehow the Dispatcher locks the Console thread and not the UI thread. Am I overlooking something here?

**The custom Application**:

```
internal sealed class CrossThreadApplication : Application
{
    private SynchronizationContext _context;

    ///=================================================================================================
    /// <summary>   Constructor. </summary>
    ///
    /// <param name="context">  The context. </param>
    ///=================================================================================================
    public CrossThreadApplication(SynchronizationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        _context = context;
    }

    ///=================================================================================================
    /// <summary>   Shows the window. </summary>
    ///
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">    Thrown when one or more required arguments are
    ///                                             null. </exception>
    ///
    /// <param name="window">   The window. </param>
    ///=================================================================================================
    public void ShowWindow(Window window)
    {
        if (window == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(window));
        _context.Send(state =>
        {
            ((Window)state).Show();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }, window);
    }

    ///=================================================================================================
    /// <summary>   Creates a new object. </summary>
    ///
    /// <param name="handle">   The creation handle for a Window. </param>
    ///
    /// <returns>   An object. </returns>
    ///=================================================================================================
    public void Create(CreationHandle<Window> handle)
    {
        _context.Send(state =>
        {
            CreationHandle<Window> hnd = (CreationHandle<Window>) state;
            hnd.Set(Activator.CreateInstance(hnd.CreationType));
        }, handle);
    }
}
```

**The UIHost class which hosts the UI thread and interacts with the application**

```
static UIHost()
{
    HostThread = new Thread(Start);
    HostThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    HostThread.Name = "UI Thread";
    CreationEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    HostThread.Start(CreationEvent);
}

private static void Start(object o)
{
    ManualResetEvent ev = (ManualResetEvent) o;

    SynchronizationContext context = new SynchronizationContext();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);

    _application = new CrossThreadApplication(context);
    ev.Set();
    _application.Run();
}

///=================================================================================================
/// <summary>   Executes the user interface operation. </summary>
///
/// <param name="windowType">   The window type. </param>
/// <param name="reset">        The reset. </param>
///
/// <returns>   An object. </returns>
///=================================================================================================
internal static object RunUI(Type windowType, ManualResetEvent reset)
{
    CreationEvent.WaitOne();
    CreationHandle<Window> handle = new CreationHandle<Window>();
    _application.Create(handle);
    _application.ShowWindow(handle.Get());
    reset.Set();
    return handle.Get();
}
```

The issue occurs in `CrossThreadApplication.ShowWindow()` at `*.Dispatcher.Run();`.

Why is this so? How can I get this working? It has to be possible somehow.

Comment: What is CreationHandle<Window> ?

Comment: It's a helper class which allows to use `SynchronizationContext.Send/Push()` with a return value since they're defined as `void`. Nonetheless I already solved the problem. Gonna add a solution as soon as I get to it.